# Can't validate anything in my layer diagram in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, architecture, modeling

I have a layer diagram, however anything I add to the layers has the "Supports Validation" property set to false and I can't change it. I have tried adding assemblies, namespaces and classes to layers with no effect.

I also tried adding my projects as layer references and I have updated VS2013 to service pack 4 in the hope it was just a bug that was solved in the meantime. All this to no avail.

So what do I need to do to get my diagram to validate all the parts? What am I missing?

Comment: Which version (edition) of Visual Studio are you using?  Ultimate, Premium, Professional?

Comment: Visual studio Ultimate 2013 service pack 4

Comment: It seems to be that on another computer with the same edition of visual studio it works. The main difference is that the system where it doesn't work has Resharper installed, so I will check if that interferes.

Comment: You could try repairing Visual Studio and then Update 4 to see if that resolves anything.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue.. please let me know if you found a solution for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. VS-2013 layerdiagram project expect the framework 4.5 or small.  for you layer project if framework is higher than 4.5 then please make it 4.5 it will work.

Comment: I'm using Vs2015, validating the architecture in layer diagram is not working targeting to .Net Framework 4.6. Is there any other way to achieve it or do we need to ask support from Microsoft? Does Microsoft stop supporting the ModelProject- Layer diagram?